# how to create an index by manually providing an index origin to a date column R

Tags: r

I am trying to index a column of dates by specifying a date origin and indexing relative to this origin.

Consider the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(DATE = seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
                                 as.Date("2010-01-10"), 
                                 by = "days"),
                 VALUE = 1:length(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
                                           as.Date("2010-01-10"),
                                           by = "days")))

print(df)

         DATE VALUE
1  2010-01-01    91
2  2010-01-02     1
3  2010-01-03    72
4  2010-01-04     2
5  2010-01-05    87
6  2010-01-06    19
7  2010-01-07    38
8  2010-01-08    96
9  2010-01-09    29
10 2010-01-10    49
```

Id like to have an index as such..

```
   index       DATE VALUE
1     -4 2010-01-01    91
2     -3 2010-01-02     1
3     -2 2010-01-03    72
4     -1 2010-01-04     2
5      0 2010-01-05    87
6      1 2010-01-06    19
7      2 2010-01-07    38
8      3 2010-01-08    96
9      4 2010-01-09    29
10     5 2010-01-10    49
```

Where "2010-01-05" is the origin date.

I've tried

```
origin_date <- as.Date("2010-01-05")

pre_origin.df <- df %>% 
  filter(DATE < origin_date) %>% 
  arrange(desc(DATE)) %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("index") %>% 
  mutate(index = index *-1)

origin.df <- df %>% 
  filter(DATE == orgin_date) %>% 
  mutate(index = 0)

post_origin.df <- df %>% 
  filter(DATE > origin_date) %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("index")

final.df <- pre_origin.df %>% 
  rbind(origin.df) %>% 
  rbind(post_origin.df) %>% 
  arrange(DATE)

print(final.df)
> final.df
   index       DATE VALUE
1     -4 2010-01-01    91
2     -3 2010-01-02     1
3     -2 2010-01-03    72
4     -1 2010-01-04     2
5      0 2010-01-05    87
6      1 2010-01-06    19
7      2 2010-01-07    38
8      3 2010-01-08    96
9      4 2010-01-09    29
10     5 2010-01-10    49
```

This works... but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of writing the code.  Possibly one that does not require 17 lines of code and the creation of three additional data frames.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are continuous then just this:

```
 df$Index <- as.integer(df$DATE-origin_date)
```

If the dates are not continuous then maybe:

```
df$Index <- 1:nrow(df) - which(df$DATE==origin_date)
```